Custom matrix operators in R
Background
I want to write a package overloading +, -, %% on matrices, to make it easier to use R for the quick matrix calculations one might do in Matlab:

+X computes t(X) (binary X+Y works as normal)
-X computes solve(X) (binary X-Y works as normal)
-I(X) computes -X
X%%Y computes Y%*%X (write multiplications right-to-left, for reasons beyond scope of question)

Example use of the package:
library(mymatrixpackage)
X <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3)
y <- matrix(1:3, nrow = 3)
+X == t(X)
X+X == 2*x

# soln to lm coefficients (remember: read right-to-left)
y%%+X%%-(X%%+X) == solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%y

Main Question
For a matrix X, how can I make +X dispatch to +.matrix (a function I can define). +X uses the internal method and seems to ignore +.matrix.
I think I need to use Ops, or something to do with group generics.
Alternative solution
I have successfully implemented this idea using an s3 class "tmatrix" and:
`+.tmatrix` <- function(X,Y) {
    if (missing(Y)) {
        t(X)
    } else {
        structure(unclass(X)+unclass(Y), class = oldClass(X))
    }
}

It would be better to not use an s3 class because:

Need to do: attr(X, "class") <- "tmatrix"
many operations (eg [) lose X's class attribute, and so I need to overload those operations as well.


I think it's a  Really Bad Idea (TM) to overload + to a completely different operation from addition.   Further, how are you going to distinguish your +X  from +  X reliably ?  MATLAB has made terrible decisions as regards parsing things like  Y*2./Y .   Considering how few keystrokes you're saving here, I don't see any upside to these operators.

I agree it's not the most robust, but it's pretty easy to see if + is being used as a binary or unary operator (just look to see if there is an object on the LHS of +). As unary + is a nullop, we don't lose anything by using it for something else. The precedences of + and - make them suitable for this use case. I find y%%+X%%-(X%%+X) pretty readable, and furthermore, I can set my editor (emacs) to look for patterns such as %%+ and render them with ', thus rendering the whole line as y'X\(X'X)`, which I find more readable and make me more inclined to use R as a matrix calculator.

I don't think you are going to be able to do this because + is implemented internally for performance reasons. Since a matrix is a fundamental type, it won't do dispatch. Kind of discussed here: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#internal-generics You need a custom class name to trigger dispatch.

@MrFlick Thanks for the link! In general, matrices can do dispatch: f <- function(x) UseMethod("f"); f.matrix <- function(x) 0; f(X) returns 0 for a matrix X. My understanding based on that section of Adv-R is: (1) Ops is a group generic (2) If x and y have class "foo", x+y can dispatch to Ops.foo, and we can define Ops.foo.  However, dispatching to Ops.matrix doesn't work. Maybe this is because matrix isn't an S3 class, but I don't understand exactly how Ops works.

it says: "internal generics do not dispatch to methods unless the class attribute has been set". This meansattr(X, "class") <- "matrix" will make X+X use Ops.matrix, whereas attr(X, "class") <- NULL will make it use the internal method.

@user615536, well that's your answer right? \+.matrix`will work as long as you set matrix class explicitly (but not otherwise), also see examples atsloop::s3_dispatch. Using a different class like your tmatrixmay be still be wise however, so you don't have the issues of overloading like Carl is concerned about, and you don't have to do this explicit setting of the attribute. Instead have atmatrix()construction function, and have users opt-in to those operations. This is also what theMatrix` package does.

I didn't mean to imply that matrix objects never dispatch, there are just optimizations for certain operators. Most math operations happen in do_arith which calls DispatchGroups to see if it should dispatch. It does a check to see if the arguments are "objects" with isObject(CAR(args)) A matrix object will return false for that check (mostly for optimization) so no dispatch happens.

@Axeman Yes, so it's best to use the "Alternative" approach, with a tmatrix construction function. An example of how it can work is here: devtools::install_github("https://github.com/tphil99/tmatrix"). The main issue is that even after the user "opts-in", many base R functions (eg. cbind) on a tmatrix will cause it to lose its class, and I'm not sure what's the best way to handle that.
